# MySQL : exclude record from UNION

Tags: mysql, union

I have an autocomplete field which queries a simple table to match "name containing string".

My concern is that I want to list the exact match first.

I perform an UNION query like that:

```
SELECT 'exact_match' AS type, name FROM table WHERE name='john'
UNION
SELECT 'match' AS type, name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%john%'
ORDER BY type, name LIMIT 30
```

But in case the user types the whole name, the result contains two records (if there is no other %john% in the table):

```
john
john
```

How can I exclude the result of one of the two queries if they perfectly match ?

I thought it was the aim of UNION (vs UNION ALL) but this is not the case, certainly because of the 'type' value.

Or maybe there is a better solution to list the exact match first ?

Comment: What you are looking for is `UNION DISTINCT`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just simply add a where clause in the second query to exclude "perfect match" as you already get them in the first query:

```
SELECT 'exact_match' AS type, name FROM table WHERE name='john'
UNION
SELECT 'match' AS type, name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%john%' AND name <> 'john'
ORDER BY type, name LIMIT 30
```

Or you could rewrite your query this way :

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN name = 'john' THEN 'exact_match' ELSE 'match' END AS type,
  name
FROM table
WHERE name like '%john%'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple query without using `UNION` / `UNION ALL` and two querys. You can use `CASE WHEN` on the `ORDER BY` to sort the found names by exakt match and match. With `DISTINCT` every name is shown once.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name 
FROM table 
WHERE name LIKE '%john%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name = 'john' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC, name ASC
LIMIT 30
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1abe5c5ab7dd1b2b612873adadeddfa2)

Answer (score 0):

in your particular case you may use

```
SELECT MIN(type) type, name
FROM ( SELECT 'exact_match' AS type, name FROM table WHERE name='john'
       UNION
       SELECT 'match' AS type, name FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%john%' ) x
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY type, name LIMIT 30
```